# TSQL: Returning customers by date descending?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Each time my user looks up a customer, I store the customer ID, Name and timestamp (timestamp = when the user performed the look up).

Kinda like:

```
ID  Name      Timestamp
1   CompanyA  2012-10-01 10:00
2   ComapnyB  2012-10-01 10:11
3   CompanyA  2012-10-01 10:22
4   CompanyA  2012-10-01 10:25
4   CompanyC  2012-10-01 10:32
```

My question is ...

I want to return TOP 30 distinct customers sorted by date descending - how do I do that?

I want to return this:

```
CompanyC
CompanyA
CompanyB
```

... only a single instance sorted by the date descending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 30 Name
FROM Customer
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY MAX(Timestamp) DESC
```